# How to read substring with ifstream C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, readfile

This is content of my file txt:

```
1        Joey        1992

2        Lisa        1996

3        Hary        1998
```

And I have a struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int ID;
    char *Name;
    int Old;
};
```

I have a main () as this:

```
int main ()
{
    MyStruct *List;
    int Rows, Columns;
    ReadFile (List, Rows, Columns, "file.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to write a function ReadFile to get information from file txt and store into a List, beside store Rows and Colums:

```
void ReadFile (MyStruct *&List, int &Rows, int &Colums, char const *path)
{
    // need help here
}
```

I know how to use ifstream to read integer from txt, but I don't know how to read substring, such as:

> "Joey", "Lisa" and "Hary"

to store each into `char *Name`.

Please help me. Thanks so much !

Comment: Store strings as `std::string` unless you enjoy debugging segmentation faults. It also makes everything you want to do easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to work on old school exercises:  you use arrays and c-string to store data elements, with all the hassle of manual memory management.

### A first (old-school) approach

I'll use only very basic language features and avoid any modern C++ features

```
void ReadFile (MyStruct *&List, int &Rows, int &Colums, char const *path)
{
    const int maxst=30;        // max size of a string
    Rows=0;                    // starting row
    ifstream ifs(path); 
    int id; 
    while (ifs>>id) {
        MyStruct *n=new MyStruct[++Rows];  // Allocate array big enough 
        for (int i=0; i<Rows-1; i++)       // Copy from old array
            n[i] = List[i]; 
        if (Rows>1)
           delete[] List;                  // Delete old array
        List = n;
        List[Rows-1].ID = id;              // Fill new element
        List[Rows-1].Name = new char[maxst];                          
        ifs.width(maxst);                 // avoid buffer overflow
        ifs>>List[Rows-1].Name;           // read into string
        ifs>>List[Rows-1].Old;                     
        ifs.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');         // skip everything else on the line
    }
}
```

This assumes that `List` and `Rows` are uninitialized when the function is called. Note that `Columns` is not used here.

Note that you'll have to clean the mess when you no longer need the `List`:  you have first to delete all the `Name` and then delete `List`.

### How to do it in more modern C++

Nowadays, you'd no longer use `char*` but `string`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int ID;
    string Name;
    int Old;
};
```

And you wouldn't use an array for keeping all the items, but a container such as `vector`:

```
int main ()
{
    vector<MyStruct> List;
    ReadFile (List, "file.txt"); // no nead for Rows. It is replaced by List.size()
    return 0;
}
```

And then you'd read it like this:

```
void ReadFile (vector<MyStruct>& List, string path)
{
    ifstream ifs(path); 
    MyStruct i;  

    while (ifs>>i.ID>>i.Name>>i.Old) {
        List.push_back(i);  // add a new item on list                     
        ifs.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');         // skip everything else on the line
    }
}
```

No worries about memory management; no worries about maximum size of strings.

Comment: Your anwser is very easy to understand, and it is helpful. Thank you so much! :)